# SQL Exit scalar function prematurely

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions

In SQL, you can exit the stored procedure prematurely with RETURN statement.

```
-- CHECK IF IT IS A VALID AND EXISTING JOB NAME
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM msdb..sysjobs WHERE name = @job_name)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('[ERROR]:[%s] job does not exist. Please check',16, 1, @job_name) WITH LOG
    RETURN
END
```

However, when I try to apply the same principle to the scalar function, it returns the error, since function needs to return something.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_GetJobStatus]
    (@job_name SYSNAME)
RETURNS INT
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @JobCompletionStatus INT;

    -- CHECK IF IT IS A VALID AND EXISTING JOB NAME
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM msdb..sysjobs WHERE name = @job_name)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('[ERROR]:[%s] job does not exist. Please check',16, 1, @job_name) WITH LOG
        RETURN   <--ERROR HERE
    END
    
    <!--Scalar function logic here -->

    RETURN @JobCompletionStatus;
END
```

How do I prematurely exit the scalar function the same way RETURN is used in the stored procedure?

Thank you.

Comment: Returns something . . . `return -1` for instance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff This is what I thought too, only RETURN 0 instead. What held me back was that my function returns INT. Wouldn't that be considered as a valid value return? I simply want to exit the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't RAISERROR or THROW in a function either.  It sounds like you really want a stored procedure with an output parameter or a resultset.

Comment: Thank you! I'll remove the RAISERROR statement then. However, what if I still want to exit scalar function prematurely, what do I do? Just return -1?

Comment: If you `return -1` then you really have to call the function from a single line of TSQL and check the return value.  At which point there's no point in having a function.  Functions are pieces of TSQL code that you call in a SQL Query or compose with other operators in complex expressions.  That's why they exist, and that's why there are restrictions on what you can do with a Function.  Stored Procedures are the general purpose procedural code encapulation mechanism in TSQL.

Comment: Thank you. If that's the case, I'll need to change the approach. But overall, do I understand correctly that you cannot exit prematurely from scalar function?

Comment: Short of something cheesy like `set @JobCompletionStatus  = 1/0;`, yes ,you understand correctly.  Also you can always return NULL, which is harder to mistake for a valid return value.